# Responsive boxes for images (css only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have four boxes next to left `div`. These four boxes will contain a image. So the requirement is when image is not available for particular section the next section  will cover the space of that `div`. I have done this but stuck while setting a height.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working as the expected result... You need to remove those `min-height`s?

Comment: When yo remove content from div then you will know the issue. for eg. if you remove all the content except "b" from right hand side div, the result should as last screen

Comment: @amit do you need to support IE8?

Comment: not at all. I have to target only morden browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result can be achieved by using `flexbox`. `Flexbox` support is pretty good http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox although you may need to provide some fallbacks for older versions of IE.

- Setting `display: flex;` defines this as a flex container and enables flex context for it's child elements
- `flex: 1 1 50%;` is shorthand for `flex-grow` (allows the element to grow if needed), `flex-shrink` (allows the element to shrink if needed) and `flex-basis` (default size of the element)
- `flex-wrap: wrap;` will allow the elements to wrap onto a new line if necessary

For further information on `flexbox` see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #F6BFBF;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.black {
    background-color: #CCEEFF
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-xs-6 div {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<strong>4 divs</strong>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>
        <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
        <div id="four" class="black">c</div>
        <div id="three" class="green">d</div>
    </div>
</div>
<strong>3 divs</strong>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>
        <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
        <div id="four" class="black">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
<strong>2 divs</strong>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>
        <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
<strong>1 div</strong>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-6 red">a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/btw8ceyy/1/

Comment: @amit Please see my updated answer. Hopefully that should explain what is happening a bit better.

Comment: Does it support IE9 ?

Comment: @amit No, unfortunately not. Support starts at IE10 with a prefix and IE11 without prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

as the other answer, but with another approach of the flexmode (without`flex:1 1 50%;` ,still a little buggy for the last parameter in some browser at this time):

```css
.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #F6BFBF;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.black {
  background-color: #CCEEFF
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}

#tow {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#one {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#four {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#three {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container,
.col-xs-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-xs-6.red {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-6 div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
}
/* if you prefer 2 cols instead 2 rows : remove hover and delete or comment */

.col-xs-6:hover div:first-child + div:last-child {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  border: solid;
}
p {
  margin:0.25em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 red">
    <p>does height matters ?</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>
    <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
    <div id="four" class="black">c</div>
    <div id="three" class="green">d</div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 red">
    <p>does height matters ?</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
    <div id="four" class="black">c</div>
    <div id="three" class="green">d</div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 red">
    <p>does height matters ?</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="four" class="black">c hover me to set us as rows </div>
    <div id="tow" class="blue">a</div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6 red">
    <p>does height matters ?</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="one" class="yellow">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WvGQMM

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-child(n)`, `:nth-last-child(n)` and `:only-child` to target specific elements based on how many siblings they have. These are supported in IE9. You can also get the full width when there are 2 elements like in the example images.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>a</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f66;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background: #6f6;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  background: #66f;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4) {
  background: #ff6;
}

.wrapper div:only-child {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4) {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

**Codepen Example**

http://codepen.io/goshdarnheck/pen/zGKvWX

Comment: This is nice but I do not want to set height manually. The height should be corresponding to left hand side div height

Comment: Aside from the height issue this is a good fallback for older browsers without flexbox support. +1